# Flutter- How to save checkbox value in the list?

Tags: flutter, checkbox

I have listview with checkbox, I saved products with ids in the list.

If product id is already saved in the the list, the checkbox value have to be true and when we remove checkbox the product id also removed from the list.

Is there any way to save the checkbox value?

This is some part of the code-

```
List<int> _selected_box = [];
```

Listview builder-

```
ListView.builder(
                                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.data.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index){
                                    return Container(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.h, horizontal: 15.w),
                                      child: Column(
                                        children: [
                                          Row(
                                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                            children: [
                                              Flexible(
                                                child: GestureDetector(
                                                  onTap: () {
                                                    futureAddMenuData = fetchAddMenuData(snapshot.data!.data[index].id, widget.prod);
                                                    futureCreateMenu = fetchCreateMenu();
                                                    _selected_box.add(index);
                                                    Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                                      msg: "Item Added to Menu!", // your toast message
                                                      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, // duration of the toast
                                                      gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM, // toast gravity
                                                      backgroundColor: Colors.black54, // background color of the toast
                                                      textColor: Colors.white, // text color of the toast
                                                    );
                                                  },
                                                  child: Row(
                                                    children:[
                                                      Container(
                                                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                                                        height: 40.h,
                                                        width: 40.w,
                                                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.w),
                                                        //margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                                                        //child: Image.asset("assets/images/MenuList.png", height: 30.h, width: 30.w,),
                                                        child:  Checkbox(
                                                          activeColor: kblue,
                                                          value: _selected_box.contains(index), // Check if index is already selected
                                                          onChanged: (value) {
                                                            setState(() {
                                                              // Check if index is already selected
                                                              if (_selected_box.contains(index)) {
                                                                _selected_box.remove(index);
                                                                Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                                                  msg: "Item Removed from Menu!", // your toast message
                                                                  toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, // duration of the toast
                                                                  gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM, // toast gravity
                                                                  backgroundColor: Colors.black54, // background color of the toast
                                                                  textColor: Colors.white, // text color of the toast
                                                                );// If selected, remove it
                                                              } else {
                                                                _selected_box.add(index);
                                                                Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                                                  msg: "Item Added to Menu!", // your toast message
                                                                  toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, // duration of the toast
                                                                  gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM, // toast gravity
                                                                  backgroundColor: Colors.black54, // background color of the toast
                                                                  textColor: Colors.white, // text color of the toast
                                                                );// If not selected, add it
                                                              }

                                                              // Update the futureAddMenuData based on the new selection
                                                              if (value == true) {
                                                                futureAddMenuData = fetchAddMenuData(snapshot.data!.data[index].id, widget.prod);
                                                              }
                                                            });
                                                          },
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                      SizedBox(
                                                        width: 15.w,
                                                      ),

                                                      //the item title and count
                                                      Column(
                                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                                        children: [
                                                          Text(
                                                            snapshot.data!.data[index].name,
                                                            maxLines: 2,
                                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                            style: TextStyle(color: kblue, fontSize: 20.sp, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                                          ),
                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                                                    ],
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                          Divider()
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  });
```